# Stopping a Razor loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, razorengine

Is there anyway to keep track of a Razor loop, and half way through it take some action, and then continue with the loop:

Eg. I have this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Assignee)
}
```

I would like (pseudo):

```
@var halfway = Model.count / 2
@var count = 0

@foreach (var item in Model) until count == halfway
{
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Assignee)
}

// hear we've reached halfway through, so I want to change add some HTML to the screen      

<hr />

@foreach remainder (var item in Model) 
{
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Assignee)
}
```

Thanks for any advice,

Mak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 @for(int i=0;i<= halfway ; i++)
 {
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Assignee)
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use LINQ on the list of your items:

```
@var halfway = Model.count / 2
@foreach (var item in Model.Take(halfway))
{
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Assignee)
}

// Do your thing
<hr />

@foreach remainder (var item in Model.Skip(halfway)) 
{
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Assignee)
}
```

Comment: sorry I just posted the same Linq answer after you, shall I delete mine?

Comment: That is ok, no worries. Just leave it there.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a `for` loop, not a `foreach` loop, provided of course your Model supports it. Then you can use count as the iterator and just check whether the `count == halfway`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it as a single loop and keep track of where you are, when you reach the halfway point you can display the additional html.

```
@{
    var halfway = Model.Count() / 2;
    var count = 0;
    var isHalfway = false;
}

@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
    if ((count >= halfway) && (!isHalfway))
    {
        isHalfway = true;
        <hr />
    }

    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Assignee)
    count++;
}
```

Another option would be to use Linq:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Take(halfway))
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.VideoCode)
}
<hr />
@foreach (var item in Model.Skip(halfway))
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.VideoCode)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit shorter option

```
@{
    var halfway = Model.Count()/2;
    var count = 0;
}
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Assignee)
    if (count++ == halfway)
    {
        <p>Your html code</p>
    }
}
```